# Create Matrix using Matrix Indices

Tags: matlab

In matlab, how could you create a matrix `M` using its indices to populate the values? For example, say I want to create a `3x3` matrix `M` such that

```
M(i,j) = i+j --> [ 2 3 4; 3 4 5; 4 5 6]
```

I tried making vectors: `x = 1:3'`, `y = 1:3` and then

```
M = x(:) + y(:)
```

but it didn't work as expected.

Any thoughts on how this can be done?

Thanks!

**UPDATE**

The `M` I actually desire is:

```
M(i,j) = -2^(-i - j).
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One way would be

```
x = 1:3;
z = ones(1,3);
N  = z'*x + x'*z
M  = -2 .^ -(z'*x + x'*z)
% Or simply 
% M = -2 .^ -N
```

Output:

```
N =

   2   3   4
   3   4   5
   4   5   6

M =

  -0.250000  -0.125000  -0.062500
  -0.125000  -0.062500  -0.031250
  -0.062500  -0.031250  -0.015625
```

Comment: Thanks, nice way to do it!

Answer (score 2):

You should use [`bsxfun`](http://www.mathworks.se/help/matlab/ref/bsxfun.html) to find the sum:

```
M=bsxfun(@plus, (1:3).', 1:3)
```

and for the second formula:

```
M=-2.^(-bsxfun(@plus, (1:3).', 1:3))
```

Comment: Thanks, that looks like what I'll need. The function I actually want is -2^(- i - j) and I can't find an example using @power. Could you demonstrate on how to use it in this case?

Comment: Then you can use `-2.^(-M)` using the `M` in the original answer.

Answer (score 1):

`bsxfun(@(x,y)(-2.^(-x-y)), (1:3).', 1:3)`

This uses the Answer of Mohsen Nosratinia with the function you wished.